# Fastest way to start a service after boot

Tags: android, android-intent, boot, bootcompleted

I would like to know what's the fastest way to start an android service after boot.

I created a broadcastreveicer that calls startService and in the android manifest I registered the receiver for the following intents:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.example.Monitor.SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="RestartServiceWhenStopped">
    <intent-filter>                
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" android:priority="999"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" android:priority="999"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" android:priority="999"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I see that, even with this high priority intent filters, my service is taking longer to receive these Android notifications than some other "less usefull" services, like, for example, whatsapp messages notification service. I noticed that whatsapp is capable of receiving a message and displaying it in the status bar before my app receives any of the above intent notifications.

I'm using Nexus 4 with Android 5.1.1 to test that.

Comment: Bearing in mind WhatsApp will receive messages via GCM which is installed at system level, so probably has higher priority than any other apps.

Comment: So an ugly workaroud would be to use GCM or FCM to start my app faster?